# How to be sure to get gps location each time you ask

Tags: android, null, geolocation, location, android-gps

In my app, people post ads that others can see. They are filtred using the distance between the creator of the annonce and the guy reading it. 
If someone post an ad, I need to be sure to get his location. If someone looks for an ad, I need to be sure to get his location to sorts the ads.

In my code, I have a way to get location but it sometimes return null.

Here is the little code (I've checked permission etc)

```
 FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationProviderClient;
    mFusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(context);

    try{
        if(mLocationPermissionsGranted){
            final Task location = mFusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation();
            location.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: found location!");

                        Location currentLocation = (Location) task.getResult();

                        if (currentLocation != null)
                        {
                            double Latit = currentLocation.getLatitude();
                            double Longit = currentLocation.getLongitude();

                            LatLng latLong = new LatLng(Latit, Longit);
                        //TODO do something with latlong
                        }
                    }else{
                        Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: current location is null");
                        Toast.makeText(context, "unable to get current location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();




                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }catch (SecurityException e){
        Log.e(TAG, "getDeviceLocation: SecurityException: " + e.getMessage() );
    }
```

But sometimes, the `Location currentLocation = (Location) task.getResult();` return null even if the task is sucessefull. I don't really know why.
I would like to know if there is a reliable way to get the location whenever I ask it (it location is enabled on the phone of course). 
Thank you

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current#last-known

Answer (score 1):

That's because you only ask to get the last location. Te device can have it if some other app has been using the gps recently but some times it takes a while until you get a location.

You should subscribe for location changes and wait until you get the first location at least. One way could be to only subscribe when you have received that the last location is null. In that case you should execute `requestLocationUpdates` with a callback asking for permissions in case you need the location if the app is in background and if you only need one location you can then stop it after the first location arrives with `removeLocationUpdates`.

Look at [the docs](https://developer.android.com/training/location/request-updates). Or you could use a library like [rxlocation](https://github.com/patloew/RxLocation) in case you feel more confortable with observables than with callbacks.